# Mongodb query to match based on 2 fields

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

Let me give a example first,

```
{
 $match: {
 $or:[
  {'sender':1, 'recipient':2},
  {'sender':2, 'recipient':1},
  {'sender':1, 'recipient':3},
  {'sender':7, 'recipient':2},
  {'sender':7, 'recipient':3} //goes on may be 20 or 30 
 ]
}
}
```

I am trying to fetch data based on the sender and the recipient. If the sender and recipient falls in this combination of categories, I pick only that data.

From the above example I can say that the combination of `sender:7` and `recipient:1` is not valid, only the combination of `sender:7` and `recipient:2` or `recipient:3` is valid.

Is there any way to simplify the above mentioned query in `C#`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write c# queries i would suggest using a repository for this it would make things much easier for you and you can write some  entity framework style queries

https://github.com/alexandre-spieser/mongodb-generic-repository

```
  public class TestMongoRepository: BaseMongoRepository, IEmailMongoRepository
    {
        public TestMongoRepository(string connectionString, string databaseName) : base(connectionString, databaseName)
        {

        }
        //public MongoRepository<T> Create<T>() where T:IEntity
        //{
        //    return new MongoRepository<T>();
        //}
    }
}
  public class Data: Document
    {

        public string Sender { get; set; }
       public string Receiver{ get; set; }

}
```

then you could query using the following syntaxt

```
var _yourRepository=new TestMongoRepository("connectionstring","database");



    class Combination{
    public int Sender{get;set;}
    public int Receiver {get;set;}
    }
var combinations=new List<Combination>{
new Combination{Sender=1, Receiver=5},
// add your other comibnaitons here

}

var data= _yourRepository.GetAll<Data>(e =>combinations.Any(c=>c.Sender=e.Sender && c.Receiver=e.Receiver) );
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. I have the repositories but i need a simplified query to match with certain combination of sender and Receiver as i have mentioned in the question, and the query you have given is confined to only sender is 1 and Receiver is 1.